# EOverflow Exception and +INF in COM DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, exception, infinity

In Delphi Seattle, I have a calculation function of the following construct:

```
try
  result := ..... // calculation
except
  // Handle (overflow) exception
end;
```

Calling this function from an EXE, works as expected and the overflow exception is trapped and handled.  However, calling the function from a COM DLL, the exception is not trapped.  By debugging, I figured out that result becomes +INF and the EOverflow exception is not raised (which has a knock-on effect further in my code).

After some experimentation I figured out that changing the function to the following does work from the COM DLL:

```
try
  result := ..... // calculation
  if result = Infinity then
    raise EOverflow.Create('Forced overflow');
except
  // Handle (overflow) exception
end;
```

I suppose I could wrap the 'if result = ... ' code in an {$IFDEF MYFLAG} block so that it only compiles for the COM DLL (which is fine as a quick-fix), but I am wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Doing some research on the web, I have come across the suggestion to use SetExceptionMask or the $FINITEFLOAT compiler directive.  SetExceptionMask seems rather tricky (side effects?) and $FINITEFLOAT seems to have no effect, which I more or less expected since ON is supposed to be the default...

Moreover, the suggestions found are all for older (even .NET) versions of Delphi, which makes me a bit weary to apply it.

Any thoughts or suggestions?  Thanks in advance for considering!

Comment: The host exe has masked floating point exceptions. Unmask exceptions at entry, restore floating point state on exit. Subject covered many times here.

Comment: I have noticed that somehow none of them provides a definitive answer.  The one getting closest is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024386/is-there-anyway-to-customise-how-net-handles-floating-point-exceptions).  However this one leaves the solution for using the DLL from C# unanswered.  Unfortunately, my DLL is used by another party who - you probably guessed it - is using C#.  At the end of the day it was more a theoretical question ("most elegant way to..."). I can get by with the added code inside an IFDEF block.  Just too bad there seems to be no definitive fix for this...

Comment: The fix is as I explained. Once you understand the problem you'll be able to implement it.

Comment: So what did you explain exactly? Is it hidden in another question on the forum? Never mind, I'll figure it out myself...

Comment: I explained it in my first comment. On entry store the floating point control word. Then set it to the Delphi default value. Finally in exit restore it to the value on entry. Its a pain in the neck.

Comment: I got that and this is how I read the solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024386/is-there-anyway-to-customise-how-net-handles-floating-point-exceptions).  However there's no conclusion on the "fix" not working when calling the DLL from C# (and that's exactly what I need).  I have a solution that works for me, so it's more out of interest.

Comment: I suspect that there was something else going on in that question. The code presented in that question is essentially accurate.